# Countable issue for PHP 7.2

Tags: php, count

I have a client that's been relying on a WP plugin for years that was abandoned by the author a few years ago. I've been able to make some fixes to make it work with an upgrade to PHP 7.2, but this one puzzles me. The more I research it, I feel like the less I understand about how to fix it.

Warning below:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /app/public/wp-content/plugins/ozh-admin-drop-down-menu/inc/core.php on line 311 (*first line below is 311*)

```
if (!count($wp_ozh_adminmenu)) {
    $wp_ozh_adminmenu = (array)get_option('ozh_adminmenu');
    unset($wp_ozh_adminmenu[0]);
}
```

Comment: Is `$wp_ozh_adminmenu` an array? Can you make sure that?

Comment: and what's the value of `$wp_ozh_adminmenu`? I guess it's a string. what about a test like... `if (!is_array($wp_ozh_adminmenu) || count($wp_ozh_adminmenu) === 0)`

Comment: Not sure I'm following, but just wrapped the above code in:

if (!is_array($wp_ozh_adminmenu) || count($wp_ozh_adminmenu) === 0) {

}

That did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before PHP 7.2 when passing a non-array to `count()`, it returned 1.
Now, as you can see in the [breaking changes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types), `count()` emits a warning when you give it a non-array.

A simple workaround is to check if it's an array before using it. It may require a bit more checks, if you want to allow arrays and string for example.

```
<?php
if (!is_array($wp_ozh_adminmenu) || !count($wp_ozh_adminmenu)) {
    $wp_ozh_adminmenu = (array)get_option('ozh_adminmenu');
    unset($wp_ozh_adminmenu[0]);
}
```

Comment: That fixed it. May take me a bit more research to understand how/why. Thanks loads!

Comment: @Ray The researches should mainly be about the plugin, what type of variables it gives to your function. It might be using several types (array or string for example), and the weak PHP typing allowed it to do so. With the PHP 7.2 breaking change you need to adapt a bit. If you only use `is_array()` and no longer allow any other type you might encounter some problems in the future when the plugin tries to use a string instead.